# How to solve a quadratically constrained optimization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I would like to solve *efficiently* the following minimization problem

min(w^T*B*w + w*g), s.t. ||w||_2 <= Delta., B is Positive Definite

This is equivalent to a "trust region step" [More' & Sorenson], which MATLAB doc say that it is used for the fsolve function.

However, the fsolve function, evaluates the function F(x) = 0, and not the minimization problem i am seeking to solve.

Any idea how to use matlab's implemeted "trust region step" for my problem?

I thougt about trying to solve the first derivative of the Lagrangian of my minimization problem. but I am not sure it will be equivalent.
i.e. using fsolve with F(x) = [(B+lambda*I)*w +g; w^T*w - Delta]
where x = [w; lambda]

Thank you in advance
Yuval

Comment: Do you need to solve it exactly?

Comment: I always recommend [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) for optimization problems in matlab. It's extremely robust and I have had great success with it.

Comment: @Nitish, approximate solution is ok.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 i'll check out your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`fsolve` solves systems of nonlinear equations.  It can use a trust region method to do so.  However, this is not what you're asking about; you're asking how to solve a specific trust-region subproblem with high accuracy.  (Your TRS is special because the objective function is convex.  TRSes can still be solved quickly if B is indefinite.)

You can find the unconstrained minimiser of your objective as -B^{-1} g/2.  If this has norm at most Delta, you're done.  Otherwise, you want to find the smallest lambda >= 0 such that -(B + lambda I)^{-1} g/2 has norm at most Delta.  There's a very fast iteration that finds an appropriate lambda using a few Cholesky factorisations, but I can't recall what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CG Steilhaug. Anything else is an overkill.

You can refer to any standard optimization textbook for details but the algorithm is *specifically* designed to solve this problem.

The code is also available [here](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~morales/PSfiles/cg_steihaug.m).